# Android - Hardcode Login not Working

Tags: java, android, authentication, hardcode, hardcoded

**Aim**

To login to my Admin.xml via AdminLogin.xml

**Flow of Classes**

AdminLoginActivity ---> AdminActivity

**AdminLoginActivityClass**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AdminLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar jAdminToolbar;

    private EditText jAdminID;
    private EditText jAdminPassword;

    private Button jAdminLoginBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_login);

        jAdminToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.adminLoginToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(jAdminToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Admin Login");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        jAdminID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adminLoginName);
        jAdminPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adminLoginPassword);
        jAdminLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adminLoginBtn);

        jAdminLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String adminLoginID = jAdminID.getText().toString();
                String adminLoginPassword = jAdminPassword.getText().toString();

                if(adminLoginID.equals("admin")&& adminLoginPassword.equals("admin")){
                    Intent intentAdmin = new Intent(AdminLoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class);
                    intentAdmin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intentAdmin);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(AdminLoginActivity.this, "Failed Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

**AdminActivityClass**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAdminAuth;
    private Toolbar jAdminToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

        mAdminAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        jAdminToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.adminToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(jAdminToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Administrator");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAdminAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null){
            sendUserToStartPage();
        }

    }

    private void sendUserToStartPage(){
        Intent intentStart = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentStart);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_admin_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.mainSignOutBtn){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            sendUserToStartPage();
        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.mainViewContactsBtn){
            Intent intentViewContacts = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, AllUsersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentViewContacts);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".SecurityApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appiconone"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appiconone"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ResidentRegistrationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AdminLoginActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.lenovo.securityapp.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AllUsersActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".UserProfileActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HelpInformationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".AdminActivity" />

</application>
```

**Problem**

1. ToolBar on AdminLogin does not allow me to return to LoginActivity when I select the back Button
2. Admin Login does not work despite entering the hardcoded input for the Admin Name and Password. After clicking on the Login button, the app prompts out a White layout for a few seconds I am brought back to the StartActivity and the Toast message does not show "Failed Login".

**SOLUTION**

The problem was because the "AdminActivityClass" had

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAdminAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null){
        sendUserToStartPage();
    }

}

private void sendUserToStartPage(){
    Intent intentStart = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentStart);
    finish();
}
```

Since the Admin login was hardcoded, the `currentUser` within the `FirebaseUser currentUser = mAdminAuth.getCurrentUser();` was set to `null`. This caused the activity to be sent back to the start page (`sendUserToStartPage();`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting your full set of code, you should be doing the following.

```
comment out the sendUserToStartPage(); inside of the currentuser == null and then try.
```

why? Because the user IS null. why? because you hard coded it into the code. The user *admin* with password *admin* does not exist in your Firebase (and if it does, you never checked it prior) so when you sign in, you do not create a session for *admin*, therefore the **current user is null**.

try doing this

```
if ("admin".equals(adminLoginID)) {
    if ("admin".equals(adminLoginPassword)) {
        //goto activity
    }
} else {
    //not admin
}
```

this might be better actually

```
if (("admin".equals(adminLoginID)) && ("admin".equals(adminLoginPassword))) {
    //goto activity
} else {
    //not admin
}
```

or even this....

```
if (("admin".equals(jAdminID.getText().toString().trim())) && ("admin".equals(jAdminPassword.getText().toString().trim()))) {
    //goto activity
} else {
    //not admin
}
```

Try this example in the manifest.
Youre manifest for the activities are missing a theme.
Also, its missed the meta-data.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Leagues.CreateLeague"
    android:label="Create League"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme2">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.aaa.bbb.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately for me, it did not work :(

Comment: It didn't work for me. After I've entered the input and clicked on the Login button, the app prompts out a White layout for a few seconds and brings me back to the StartActivity.

Comment: remove the finish tag finish();

Comment: and the return; tag in the else statement. no reason for this.

Comment: I still have the same problem :(  I've rechecked the activities' name and everything seems to be right....just that I am unable to sign in

Comment: I really appreciate your help, please don't give up but......it still not working. I really don't understand why isn't it working, the inputs are correct and so is the If else statement.....but it can't work.

Comment: post code to your other activities.. show this. AdminActivity. whats your mainactivity? post that too if u have it

Comment: I've just posted it but I am able to sign into my MainActivity

Comment: comment out the sendUserToStartPage(); inside of the currentuser == null and then try.

Comment: YES!!!! IT WORKS NOW!!! FINALLY!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Please add your comment into your solution. I'll mark it as answered. Thank you so much and Have a Nice Day.

Comment: i put it in my answer and gave an explanation as to why that worked. happy coding.

Comment: Its because, when I logged into the admin account, the FirebaseAuth was checking for the current user and when it couldn't detect the registered user...as the admin was hardcoded...it prompted me back out to the main page as if I was signing out. That's why the toast didn't show and a white screen appeared. Just like the code, if "currentUser == null" which it is....sendUserToStartPage...its null because of the hardcoded input. Am I right? =D

Comment: yes, you are right. when learning code its important for you to figure it out, but way more important to know WHY.

Comment: Yes!! you're right!!! Finding out why the problem occurred in the first place is way more important. It will allow me to debug better and I will be thinking of a lot more possibilities if such problems were to occur again. Thank you again

Comment: you got it. happy coding

Comment: Happy coding to you too!!

Answer (score 0):

## Try like this smartly

- take a `String` variable globally and    `declare and intialise` them
- in next step you need to add validations

---

```
String str_admin="admin";
if ((str_admin.equals(adminLoginID)) && (str_admin.equals(adminLoginPassword))) {
//pass reference of activity which you want to open it 
 } else {
//not admin
 }
```

---

## Happy to help yoh

Comment: Thank you Vishal, but I found out that the problem was not about the if else statement, its because, when I logged into the admin account, the FirebaseAuth was checking for the current user and when it couldn't detect the registered user...as the admin was hardcoded...it prompted me back out to the main page as if I was signing out. That's why the toast didn't show and a white screen appeared. Just like the code, if "currentUser == null" which it is....sendUserToStartPage...its null because of the hardcoded input.